# How do I center an element loaded in frame in Java GWT?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I loaded an html using `frame.setUrl(PATH);`

It works properly but I want to show it centered horizontally, there are no methods on the frame object that is similar to `.setHorizontalAlignment` of panel widgets.

How can I center elements in `GWT frames`?

I am using Eclipse as IDE with `GWT Plugin`.

EDIT: I am using com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Frame;

Comment: Show some piece of code. What frame are you talking about?

Comment: @Braj I am using com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Frame;

Comment: I have posted an answer. Please have a look.

Comment: @Braj thanks, turns out I only have to enclose the elements in these <div id="container" align="center"></div>, thanks!

Comment: and `RootPanel.get("container")` in Entry point class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just enclose the `iframe` inside a `div` that is `center` aligned.**

Try this one

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

    // Make a new frame, and point it at Google.
    Frame frame = new Frame("http://www.google.com/");

    // Add it to the root panel.
    RootPanel.get("container").add(frame);

}
```

JSP/HTML:

```
...
<body> 
      <div id="container" align="center"></div>
</body>
...
```

---

or try this that is same as above but `div` is created in JAVA code

```
// Make a new frame, and point it at Google.
Frame frame = new Frame("http://www.google.com/");

DivElement div = Document.get().createDivElement();
div.setAttribute("align", "center");

div.appendChild(frame.getElement());

// Add it to the root panel.
RootPanel.get().getElement().appendChild(div);
```